# OpenCV finding contours

Tags: python, opencv

We are part of a FIRST robotics team that is using OpenCV for vision detection. Other teams have posted a working detection software This can be found on team2053tigertronics's Github (/2016Code/blob/master/Robot2016/src/vision/vision.cpp) and we are attempting to convert their code into Python as using this code as sample code that we can adjust later. While converting, we ran into a weird issue. 
For debugging purposes we are using a print statement to print the contours so that we knew why we got the error when we tried to put the code into the boundingRectangle method
Here is our code so far:http://pastebin.com/7zh4c7Ej
Here is our output: http://pastebin.com/5fRQhC28

The error we are getting:

Traceback:
in line 146, processImage()
in line 98: rec = cv2.boundingRect(i[x])
index 256 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15/
Our output has been a list of different numpy arrays that hold integer   values. We are confused on how to use these values to draw rectangles and   eventually use these values for coordinates for use during the robotics   game.

We appreciate any help!!!
Thanks!
Axton (and Team)

EDIT:
As asked for by other members, here is a more simpler question:

Here is our code that we are having problems with:
    filler, contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(matThresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

```
    for i in contours:

        for x in i:
            rec = Rect()
            print i[x]
            rec = cv2.boundingRect(i[x])
```

We would like to know how to use the contour values as points to use the boundingRect method. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Edit only the relevant part of the code into the question.

Comment: I changed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not very much comfortable with Python, but it shouldn't be just: `rec = cv2.boundingRect(i)` ?

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed as easy as @Miki said above.

since `contours` is a list of contours, you only need **one** loop to access a single contour, and get the bounding rect of that:

```
for contour in contours:
    rec = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    print rec
    ## now, just for the fun, let's look
    ## at a *single* contour, it consists of points:
    for point in contour:
        print point
```

Comment: When I tried doing that, it was throwing out of bound errors. Ill try again. Thanks!